# Form Data Not posting to database

Tags: php, mysqli

Can Anyone see what is wrong with the below code.
When I submit the data using HTML form I get as expected the confirmation to confirm Registered. However, when I check the database its not there!

I have checked the names are the same names of each input is correct and can confirm the database is connected successfully, along with the names of the database columns ect...

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<?php 

    if (isset($_POST['carrierinsert'])) {

    $acc = $_POST['acc'];  


   $sql = "SELECT cariers.acc FROM cariers WHERE cariers.acc ='$acc'";
   $result = $db->query($sql);

   if($result->num_rows > 0) {

        echo "<font color='red'>Carrier Already exits</font>"; 


  $sql = "INSERT INTO cariers ( `reg`, `acc`, `accstatus`, `carramid`, `carrfloor`, `pay`, `comms`) 
    VALUES ( '".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['reg'])."', 
             '".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['acc'])."', 
             '".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['accstatus'])."', 
             '".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['carramid'])."',       
             '".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['carrfloor'])."',  
             '".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['pay'])."',        
             '".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['comms'])."' )";


        $insert = $db->query($sql);

                    echo "<font color='red'>Carrier Inserted</font>";

        }
        }
         ?> 


                <h1>Add New</h1>
                <hr>




            <form method="post" action=""> Carrier<br />




            <input name="reg" type="text" required="required" value=""> 
            <br /><br />




            Number<br />
            <input name="acc" type="text" required="required" value="">
            <br /><br />



            Status<br />
            <input name="accstatus" type="text" required="required" value="">





            Floor<br />
            <select name="carrfloor" id="carrfloor">
            <option name="carrfloor" Value="1">1</option>
            <option name="carrfloor" Value="2">2</option>
            </select>
            <br /><br />




            Pay<br />
            <select name="pay" id="pay">
            <option selected="selected" name="pay" Value="0">N/A</option>
            <option name="pay" Value="1">1%</option>
            <option name="pay" Value="1.25">1.25%</option>
            <option name="pay" Value="1.5">1.5%</option>
            <option name="pay" Value="1.75">1.75%</option>
            <option name="pay" Value="2">2%</option>
            <option name="pay" Value="2.25">2.25%</option>
            <option name="pay" Value="2.50">2.50%</option>
            <option name="pay" Value="3.00">3%</option>
            </select>
            <br /><br />



            Additional Charge<br />
            <select name="comms" id="comms">
            <option name="comms" selected ="selected" Value="Fees">Yes</option>
            <option name="comms" Value="No Fees">No</option>
            </select>
            <br /><br />



            Manager<br />
            <select name="carramid" id="carramid">
            <option name="carramid" Value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option name="carramid" Value="No">No</option>
            </select>
            <br /><br />


            <br /><br />
            <input type="submit" class="btn" name="carrierinsert" value="Save" />


            </form>
```

Comment: Switch one quotes to double one in sql variable. __'__ -> __"__

Comment: well something obviously failed you and you didn't check for errors whatsoever; what'd you expect, *magic?*

Comment: Not to mention your leaving out the HTML form that should have been posted with this. So, how do we know that isn't also failing here?

Comment: I have updated my original Post witch include the HTML

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO cariers ( reg, acc, accstatus, carramid, carrfloor, pay, comms) 
        VALUES ( '".{$db->real_escape_string($_POST['reg'])}."', 
                 '".{$db->real_escape_string($_POST['acc'])}."', 
                 '".{$db->real_escape_string($_POST['accstatus'])}."', 
                 '".{$db->real_escape_string($_POST['carramid'])}."',       
                 '".{$db->real_escape_string($_POST['carrfloor'])}."',  
                 '".{$db->real_escape_string($_POST['pay'])}."',        
                 '".{$db->real_escape_string($_POST['comms'])}."' )";
```

UPDATE

```
$a = 15;

    echo 'this will not write 15: $a'
        .PHP_EOL.
        "this will write 15: $a"
        .PHP_EOL.
        "but i can escape a variable anyways. i dont need to change quotes".$a.' dot (.) is the add method for strings'
        ;
```

Comment: can you explain what you did here?

Comment: I changed as per Mehmet and its saying that on  -Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ' on line 19 Which is VALUES ( '".{$db->real_escape_string($_POST['reg'])}."',

Comment: Yep u right. it's brackets. just remove them. why did u need them ?

Comment: I updated it and still nothing is inserting, only this time its not even saying its been inserted. Obviously because its not.

Comment: If you can pass __if (isset($_POST['carrierinsert']))__ condition there should be one message. registered or insterted. so what u get?

Comment: I dont get anything now, which means its failed. I have no updated my original post to include HTML.

Comment: __$db__, is it a mysqli object? what's it?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO cariers ( `reg`, `acc`, `accstatus`, `carramid`, `carrfloor`, `pay`, `comms`) 
        VALUES ( '".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['reg'])."', 
                 '".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['acc'])."', 
                 '".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['accstatus'])."', 
                 '".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['carramid'])."',       
                 '".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['carrfloor'])."',  
                 '".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['pay'])."',        
                 '".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['comms'])."' )";
```

**EDITTED:**
try this code

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['carrierinsert'])) {
        $acc = $_POST['acc'];  
        $sql = "SELECT cariers.acc FROM cariers WHERE cariers.acc ='$acc'";
        $result = $db->query($sql);

        if($result->num_rows > 0) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Carrier Already exits</font>"; 
        }else{

            $sql = "INSERT INTO cariers ( `reg`, `acc`, `accstatus`, `carramid`, `carrfloor`, `pay`, `comms`)  VALUES ( '".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['reg'])."', '".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['acc'])."','".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['accstatus'])."','".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['carramid'])."', '".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['carrfloor'])."','".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['pay'])."','".$db->real_escape_string($_POST['comms'])."' )";
            $insert = $db->query($sql);
            echo "<font color='red'>Carrier Inserted</font>";
            }
        }
?> 


<h1>Add New</h1>
<hr>
<form method="post" action=""> Carrier<br />
        <input name="reg" type="text" required="required" value=""> 
        <br /><br />
    Number<br />
        <input name="acc" type="text" required="required" value="">
        <br /><br />
    Status<br />
        <input name="accstatus" type="text" required="required" value="">
    Floor<br />
        <select name="carrfloor" id="carrfloor">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
        <br /><br />
    Pay<br />
        <select name="pay" id="pay">
            <option selected="selected" value="0">N/A</option>
            <option value="1">1%</option>
            <option value="1.25">1.25%</option>
            <option value="1.5">1.5%</option>
            <option value="1.75">1.75%</option>
            <option value="2">2%</option>
            <option value="2.25">2.25%</option>
            <option value="2.50">2.50%</option>
            <option value="3.00">3%</option>
        </select>
    <br /><br />
    Additional Charge<br />
        <select name="comms" id="comms">
            <option selected ="selected" value="Fees">Yes</option>
            <option value="No Fees">No</option>
        </select>
        <br /><br />
    Manager<br />
        <select name="carramid" id="carramid">
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
        <br /><br />
        <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" class="btn" name="carrierinsert" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: why should they *try this* ? enlighten us ;-)

Comment: that downvote you just got, isn't mine. Just so you know that.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add double quotes. I update query please see now

Comment: I updated it and still nothing is inserting, only this time its not even saying its been inserted. Obviously because its not.

Comment: I have updated my original Post witch include the HTML

Comment: So now I have included the full PHP and Html form(excluding the db connection) Can Anyone see whats wrong as I have tried the above with the sql varible